# Setting class when calling createLabel

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm using Titanium Studio and Titanium SDK. In this case I'm developing for Android but I have an installation on OSX too.

When using Alloy, I can specify

```
<Label class="header" id="someId">Week 50</Label>
```

and then specify the colors,fonts etc in the TSS file like this

```
".header": {
  color: "blue"
}
```

However when I use the SDK version:

```
var l = Ti.UI.createLabel({class:"header", text:"sometext"});
```

The color from the TSS file isnt picked up???

What am I doing wrong. Isn't 'class' a valid property? (I cant seem to find it in the docs).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alloy style are applied automatically to views created through xml. If you want to keep that effect while you are creating objects inside controller you have to use [$.UI.create()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Alloy.Controller.UI-method-create) method instead of Titanium API. In your case your code will look like this:

```
var l = $.UI.create('Label', {
   title: "sometext",
   classes: ["header"],
});
```

For more read [Dynamic Styles guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Dynamic_Styles). It's not very well documented and some parts of it were unclear for me when I read it but it's good starting point to experiment with the code and learn Alloy behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I had missed the $.UI.create() call. However I could only get it to work with the following syntax:  var label = $.UI.create('Label', {text:"sometext", classes:["header"]}); Any comments why the syntax differs?

Comment: Sorry, I forget about different property. I've changed my answer to make it fully correct.

Comment: Great Work. Hope Titanium Does something to simplify this.

Comment: I fail to create a `Widget` using that code.. And of course, no documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered you question while I was searching for something similar. The chosen answer was unfortunately not the solution I was looking for, since I was writing a commonJS and needed the same this. If you are writing a commonJS (but still under an Alloy project) you can use the following solution:

```
var l = Alloy.UI.create("index", "Label", {
   title: "sometext",
   classes: ["header"],
});
```

Where `"index"` is what being generated by Alloy from you `app.tss` file.